# my url data is missing when sharing to facebook

Tags: php

I have a problem when I want to share the results of the page via Facebook, when I share via Facebook there is some data in the url that is missing so the page results cannot be displayed in full because of the loss of the data, I think I did the right thing but why is this not working, I'm confused when I want to find a solution through Google what keywords to use:

[my source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4Bbf.png)

[and here when i hover facebook share icon, its works, but when i open it some data is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBglV.png)

I do not know where the error is

Answer (score -1):

to share url, use `urlencode` for your query string first

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?= urlencode("https://domain/login/bagikan.php?user=" . $_SESSION['pelajar'] . "&judul=" . $_SESSION['judul']) ?>
```